# PHP with MySQL is slow

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance, xampp

**(IMPORTANT) EDIT 3:** Running the testajax2.php by itself and *not* Ajax. The duration is about the same, 1.02-1.03 seconds. So I guess that means the problem is in PHP-MySQL or [XAMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP)??

When I ran it through a [phpMyAdmin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpMyAdmin) query, here's the result: Showing rows 0 - 29 ( ~50 total. The query took **0.0015 seconds**). It appears the problem lies not in Ajax after all, but perhaps in PHP. How can I fix this? (I've also just edited the question title.)

**Answer:** Add the following line in the hosts file located in `”C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc”`

```
   127.0.0.1 localhost
```

---

*The question before:*

Is it  normal for jQuery Ajax with SQL queries on the other side have the **minimum duration of 1 second**? I've tried `$.get`, `$.post`,`$.getjson`,`$.ajax({type:'POST'})`, `$.ajax({type:'GET'})`. As I've said, it's the minimum. It could get worse to about 3 seconds even. I doubt it's the SQL queries though, as when I try them in phpMyAdmin, the results come up extremely fast.

It doesn't matter also if the queries are very simple and the table only has 2 elements, it would still follow the 1 sec minimum. I'm using the latest XAMPP, and I don't know if it matters, but I'm accessing the files through localhost and 127.0.0.1.

I'm running it on a local environment, on the same laptop I made these files on. jQuery is updated. The returned value/array is json_encoded. I'm using mysqli. The database is in [InnoDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InnoDB), and within are only about five tables, and there are hardly anything on them. Here's a very simple sample query:

#### File `index.php`

```
    var test_id =2;
    testcall();
    function testcall(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'testajax2.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {test_id: test_id},
            success: function(data){

            }
        });
    }
```

#### File `testajax2.php`

```
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'testdb');
    $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Connection Failed: " . mysqli_connect_errno();
        exit();
    }

    $testreceive = $_POST['test_id'];
    $query = "SELECT First_Name from tblperson";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
    $row = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    echo json_encode($row);
```

The tblperson contains 50 records, and there are only four columns. According to Firebug, it took 1.03 seconds to do that extremely simple task. I'm not sure what it really means, but viewing through the *Net* tab in [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29), the bar is entirely violet. 0 and 1.03 seconds Waiting. +1.03 seconds and 0 receiving.

It also doesn't matter if I send them as `json_encode($row)` or `foreach($row as $value){ echo $value['First_Name']; }`. It would still be about at least 1 second. I've tried on Chrome and Safari, and though I can't have the exact duration, I can tell that it's about the same. But for a simple Ajax call with *no SQL queries*. If I remember correctly, it's very fast. I'd be back with a sample and duration output.

Comment: We require more info, your context is too vague. Do you have a link where we can try it? How much ajax calls do you have simultaneously? Is your environment local or remote? ....

Comment: Can you show the relevant code?

Comment: For me / my setup this is not normal no.. locally my ajax requests (on average, according to firebug) are completed within 140ms. But as the other comment says.. we have no idea what's happening on your machine, how complex the scripts are.

Comment: How many time does it takes for your app to respond to the same request directly (not ajax) ? how many time does it takes the query itself to execute in the mysql cli ? through php ? very likely the error is not ajax. Unless you have a weird condition in your server, the reason should be either in the encoding you're doing with the output sent to ajax (json ?) or, more likely, the sql itself. More data is needed to provide guidance.

Comment: Sorry, just added more details. Running the testajax2.php directly yield about the same duration as when I called it with Ajax. Sigh! I don't know what else to do from here.. Help please.

Comment: just another hint : request through $.ajax or $.load are usually very fast for me, faster than the regular page access, sql or not, so as your edit3 pinpoints problem must likely reside on the server side, possibly in the php configuration (new framework?) or in the apache/whatev config (new server?)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm using the latest XAMPP build. How frustrating... Could I just edit the .ini for whatever it is..php.ini maybe? Something that can affect the "0 and 1.03s Waiting. +1.03s and 0 Receiving" (if that even means anything)

Comment: Or maybe I should just reinstall Apache, PHP, MySQL, and phpmyadmin..and not use XAMPP (would that by the way delete the present config?). Perhaps that would more likely solve my problem? What do you guys think?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add the following line in the hosts file located in `”C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc”`

```
   127.0.0.1 localhost
```

This solved my problem. PHP-MySQL can now complete its task depending on how complex somewhere between 20-500 ms.

Comment: The link is broken, but the answer saved me! My tests was taking ~56 secs to run. Now, less than 2!!

Comment: I had that line at the bottom of my hosts file with 10+ records and I had 2 seconds delay, I had to move the line to the top and now there is no delay

Comment: Sometimes it is worth to change server name to 127.0.0.1 in PHP code or your CMS config file, like `$mysqli = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'testdb');`

Answer (score 15):

It could be happening in a couple of places: 1) the query itself, or 2) the creation of the mysqli instance (and resulting db connection). If I had to guess, I suspect your problem is (2).

One quick-and-dirty debugging method is to use `microtime()`.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php

Example:

```
$start = microtime(TRUE); // Start counting

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'testdb');

$temp = microtime(TRUE) - $start;
echo "Time to connect: {$temp}";  // Check elapsed time

$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Connection Failed: " . mysqli_connect_errno();
    exit();
}

$temp = microtime(TRUE) - $start;
echo "Time to setup: {$temp}";  // Check elapsed time

$testreceive = $_POST['test_id'];
$query = "SELECT First_Name from tblperson";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

$temp = microtime(TRUE) - $start;
echo "Time to query: {$temp}";  // Check elapsed time

$row = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$temp = microtime(TRUE) - $start;
echo "Time to fetch {$temp}";  // Check elapsed time
```

Comment: It's been solved. But your tip could come in handy next time. Pls don't delete it. Thanks. I'll upvote it when I reach 15 rep

Comment: Thank you for your code, but there is an error inside. In row 14 you use $temp instead of $start!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the localhost lookup from localhost to 127.0.0.1.

The solution is to either add the line `127.0.0.1 localhost` to your windows hosts file as @Wap has answered (and thank you for you answer!)

Or if you do not have access to the hosts file, you can simply change localhost to 127.0.0.1 in your php mysqli call:
`$mysqli = new mysqli('127.0.0.1'), 'root', '', 'testdb');`