# PHP with database(mysql) load too slow in localhost

Tags: php, xampp, localhost

`[13:58:08.334] POST http://localhost/hubcraze/@webpages/authenticate.php [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 1046ms]
[13:58:09.416] GET http://localhost/hubcraze/ [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 0ms]`

Why is that authenticate.php(with database connection) loads around 1000ms while before it only took less than 100ms to load the page?

Comment: "Before" what? What does it do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line to the hosts which is located at ”C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc” make sure that you have admin privilege to edit the file.

127.0.0.1 localhost

Refer to this [PHP with MySQL is Slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13584360/php-with-mysql-is-slow-solved?rq=1)

Comment: its already there still slow !