# Why does making a connection to MySQL take about 2 seconds in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, xampp

My code is:

```
$start = time();
$sqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "mySelectedPass", "mydb");       
echo time() - $start;
```

Result: 2.

What's the problem?

I'm using XAMPP 1.8.1 and Windows 8.

Ans: Use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost :)

Comment: How are you measuring the SQL request time? Are you sure you are only measuring the MySQL execution time and not other PHP/framework overhead?

Comment: Thank you for answer. I use firebug-> network tab. The hole code that I ran is same as question code.

Comment: Try measuring only the execution of the `query` function. Save `microtime()` to variable just before and to another just after and print the difference between the two.

Comment: Try using PHP to time the SQL execution time. `echo` the `time()` right before you create your connection and then right after your `while` loop.

Comment: Thank you. I used your approaches to measure time and By using @tadman answer I found that this time is related to making connection I updated question title too. any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're testing the time it takes to connect to the server *and* run the query, whereas in your SQL admin tool you're only testing the query execution time.

You might have something misconfigured that makes connecting to your database server really slow. Most applications should use a connection pool to avoid having to reconnect to the database on every single request.

Comment: Thank you. I measured connection time and it takes 2 sec. what configurations I have to modify?

Comment: Most likely the server is trying to resolve your IP address and failing. This is the [`skip-name-resolve`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/host-cache.html) configuration parameter. The connection time will still be fairly slow compared to your query, so look at using [persistent connections](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.persistconns.php).

Comment: There is a question I think is related to this issure http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13584360/php-with-mysql-is-slow-solved . As you described and in you link I have to modify hosts file in C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc but I cant modify it because windows says : this file is opened by other application.

Comment: I applied p: approach in my connection. The problem is that i use Yii and active record and I changed connection string in main config file But anything does'nt changed

Comment: Thank you @tadman. I did some search and found some related question. I used 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost and it works very fast. I accepted your answer because this is near to my applied approach. Plz edit it to use by others.