# Mysql slow with php

Tags: php, mysql

I have, working with MYSQL and PHP, many tables linked by `id` with `left join.

When I execute the query with php it is very slow and it take 20 to 21 sec, executed with php from `localhost`, but when i execute the consult in mysql with the same value (from `mysql-slow. log`), that is very fast, i can not check the process because is very fast.

I try with `limit =5` in the query but is the same result

**Update**
My consult have this form

```
Select tba._1,tba._2,tbb._2,tbb_3,tbc_4.....tbx._1
From main_table mt left join table_a tba on tba.id = mt.id
     left joint table_b tbb on tbb.id = mt.id
     left joint table_c tbc on tbc.id = mt.id
     ...
    ...
    left joint table_x tbx on tbx.id=mt.id    
Group By mt.id
```

**size of my tables**
[image]

Comment: Share the query that you are using.

Comment: And maybe also the number of record in the tables involved in the query.

Comment: Did you time just the query itself, or also the processing done by php?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be more a dns resolution than a MySQL request issue.
look at https://serverfault.com/questions/66347/why-is-the-response-on-localhost-so-slow

Comment: please to clarify, i need change `ServerName localhost:80` to `ServerName mypublicip:80` rigth?

Comment: This problem can come from different reasons. Try first changing localhost:80 by 127.0.0.1:80

Comment: i think is dns because when i add in etc/drivers/host `127.0.01 localhost` in  the same server the web opened fast, but next i change http.config that is slow,

Comment: i try with `127.0.01:80` , `myip:80`, `domainwithoutwww:80`, and `www.domain.com:80` but always is slow,

Comment: have a look as well on that link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13584360/php-with-mysql-is-slow-solved